# Get lines of Sudoku grid with open cv

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv, image-recognition, sudoku

I am developing an app that will solve Sudoku from camera. I am using OpenCV library. I spent some time researching and I decided to try with [this](https://github.com/ErnestWong/SudokuSolver-AndroidStudio/blob/master/sudokuSolver) project, since I am totally new in image recognition .

I have a problem with detecting grid lines. With code I have, app detects only one horizontal or one vertical line(depends on threshold, 51 and below returns one vertical and 52 and above returns one horizontal). Here is my function for finding corners, where I am detecting lines:

```
private List<Point> findCorners(Mat mat) {
    Mat lines = new Mat();
    List<double[]> horizontalLines = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    List<double[]> verticalLines = new ArrayList<double[]>();

    //Imgproc.GaussianBlur( mat, lines, new Size(5, 5), 2, 2 );
    int threshold = 150;
    int minLineSize = 0;
    int lineGap = 10;
    //Imgproc.Canny(mat, lines, 70, 100);
    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(mat, lines, 1, Math.PI / 180, threshold);

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.cols(); i++) {
        double[] line = lines.get(0, i);
        double x1 = line[0];
        double y1 = line[1];
        double x2 = line[2];
        double y2 = line[3];
        if (Math.abs(y2 - y1) < Math.abs(x2 - x1)) {
            horizontalLines.add(line);
        } else if (Math.abs(x2 - x1) < Math.abs(y2 - y1)) {
            verticalLines.add(line);
        }
    }
    String lineInfo = String.format(
            "horizontal: %d, vertical: %d, total: %d",
            horizontalLines.size(), verticalLines.size(), lines.cols());
    Log.d(TAG_HOUGHLINES, lineInfo);

    // find the lines furthest from centre which will be the bounds for the
    // grid
    double[] topLine = horizontalLines.get(0);
    double[] bottomLine = horizontalLines.get(0);
    double[] leftLine = verticalLines.get(0);
    double[] rightLine = verticalLines.get(0);

    double xMin = 1000;
    double xMax = 0;
    double yMin = 1000;
    double yMax = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < horizontalLines.size(); i++) {
        if (horizontalLines.get(i)[1] < yMin
                || horizontalLines.get(i)[3] < yMin) {
            topLine = horizontalLines.get(i);
            yMin = horizontalLines.get(i)[1];
        } else if (horizontalLines.get(i)[1] > yMax
                || horizontalLines.get(i)[3] > yMax) {
            bottomLine = horizontalLines.get(i);
            yMax = horizontalLines.get(i)[1];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < verticalLines.size(); i++) {
        if (verticalLines.get(i)[0] < xMin
                || verticalLines.get(i)[2] < xMin) {
            leftLine = verticalLines.get(i);
            xMin = verticalLines.get(i)[0];
        } else if (verticalLines.get(i)[0] > xMax
                || verticalLines.get(i)[2] > xMax) {
            rightLine = verticalLines.get(i);
            xMax = verticalLines.get(i)[0];
        }
    }

    // obtain four corners of sudoku grid
    Point topLeft = ImgManipUtil.findCorner(topLine, leftLine);
    Point topRight = ImgManipUtil.findCorner(topLine, rightLine);
    Point bottomLeft = ImgManipUtil.findCorner(bottomLine, leftLine);
    Point bottomRight = ImgManipUtil.findCorner(bottomLine, rightLine);

    List<Point> corners = new ArrayList<Point>(4);
    corners.add(topLeft);
    corners.add(topRight);
    corners.add(bottomLeft);
    corners.add(bottomRight);

    return corners;
}
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e_Pkyfd_VAbYnAxiSts0sYJs_mWdtxMl/view?usp=sharing) is the input image

Comment: Please provide input images.

Comment: It's really hard to detect all the lines in a sudoku image. Instead just detect the outer box and after view point transformation, divide the box into equal cells (with the assumption that all cells are of equal size in birds eye view).

Comment: @eldesgraciado I've added a link so you can see the input image.

Comment: @soumith If I understand this code well, these lines are just used for finding corners. I am not sure how to divide box into equal cells. It would be great if you can provide some code!